# Acceptable Question?

Tags: support, questions

My apologies, I am not 100% clear on which questions belong in SO.
Specifically, I want to ask why I cannot write queries in SQL Server
that follow the logical order https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement  . Is this the type of question one may ask in SO?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a [Help], which includes a page on [what questions can be asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @usr2564301:  Gonna be blunt here - that's not useful advice right now.

Comment: @Makoto: does it not answer "I am not 100% clear on which questions belong in SO"?

Comment: @usr2564301: Sorry, did not see it, I am posting it there now.

Comment: @usr2564301:  I get that it's easy and convenient to provide some generic copy-paste advice, but more times than not, situations like this beg for more detailed discussion rather than "go read this".  If you explain the situation, you have a better shot of being able to reach someone and explain in *detail* what their question is lacking and how they can successfully pass our standards.

Comment: Seriously, a downvote? I make an effort to ask in here , not knowing anywhere else to ask, to avoid trashing SO, and I don't even get a real comment by the downvoter?

Comment: Downvotes here can indicate just something like "I don't think that question is on-topic", i.e., disagreement with the posted question, and have no effect on your reputation.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: While this is true, that's arguably misuse of the voting system, though likely due to carelessness rather than malice. Support questions should generally be downvoted only if there is some fault or lack in the request for support itself.

Answer (score 5):

It *can* be the type of question you ask here if you demonstrate:

- What query you're trying to write
- What the error is you're encountering
- What your objective is in writing this query (e.g. "I expect to get back records which match *foo* and don't contain *bar* between *X* and *Y*.")

At face value I'm not seeing much good here with your question since it's unspecific in its current form.  You're asking about "logical processing order", and I must confess, even though I know some things about SQL and not much about SQL Server, "logical processing order" means nothing to me.  You're going to want to supplement this with an actual statement that you've written and that you're running into an error with.

Comment: Logical processing order refers to the availability of data. Them, e.g., 'Select' precedes 'Where' if the data gathered in 'Select' is available when we use the 'Where' clause. I have tried many queries that respect the Logical order but all I get in return is error messages.I will paste in the error message.

Comment: Okay then.  Put together an example in actual SQL which you would expect to run.  Edit that into your main question.  That's kind of the only missing piece here.